# Understanding descriptions from novel

Tags: parsing, comprehension

From the beginning of *House of Suns* by Alastair Reynolds

> Chimneys and turrets, belvederes and clock towers punctuated the
> haphazard, dinosaur-backed roofline. Some parts of the house were only one or two
> storeys high; others had twenty or more levels, with the tallest parts rising like
> mountains from the foothills of surrounding structures. Windowed bridges spanned the
> gaps between towers, a silent, distant figure occasionally **stealing behind their
> illuminated portholes**. It was **less a house than a city** in which you could walk from one
> side to the other without ever stepping outside.

I have no idea what the bold phrases are supposed to mean. Can anyone translate or reword these phrases into simple English for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The house (as described) was so large and sprawling that it was more like a city than a house. The bridges between towers had windows in them (and presumably also roofs). You could sometimes see a figure creeping past these windows, which are compared to the portholes in a ship.

Comment: Thanks, the words "stealing" and "than" was throwing me off in the first place...